# Setting different compiler flags when "Running" and "Debugging" app

Tags: c++, android-studio, cmake, android-ndk

I would like my native code to run `-O3` optimisation whenever I hit **"Run (Shift+F10)"** in Android Studio and `-O0` when I hit **"Debug (Shift+F9)"**. How would I achieve this in `CMakeLists` or in `build.gradle` for my app?

I couldn't find what I am looking for through Google.

Any help is appretiated!

Comment: You need to have two different builds, one release build using optimization, and one debug build without (and with debug information). This isn't something you set for "Run" or "Debug", but rather by detecting what is currently being built (in your build script) and setting the flags accordingly.

Comment: why ask here? just check cmake documentation... it's explained there... use simply `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_XXX` where `XXX` can be `RELEASE`, `DEBUG` ....

Comment: @elvis.dukaj I would like the functionality to be tied to the Run and Debug buttons. I don't want to switch between Release and Debug build.

Comment: But what if you only want to *run* your debug build, to test a simple thing without having to step through code in the debugger? Then that won't be possible. Starting a debugger or having the program running through one is usually more resource intensive and slower than just plain running your application. While you are in active development you do it using the debug build configuration, running and debugging as needed. Then when you're done you switch to release mode and make (hopefully) one single build, and that's it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That is why I would like my debug build to run at full optimization when I hit Run. So I can test my code at full speed. However when I hit Debug, I am now probably stepping through the code and I don't want it to be optimized, so I can actually see what is going on. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..

cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo ..